# Can I cycle to Frankfurt Hahn airport from Koblenz?

Tags: germany, bicycles, hhn, rhine

I am cycling down the Rhine this summer and I expect I will get as far as Koblenz. I would like to know if I can get from Koblenz to Frankfurt Hahn airport on my bike, maybe in 2 days ride down the Mosel.

I need to know at what point I should leave the riverbank and head to the airport. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that should be absolutely possible and a pretty nice route. There are bicycle paths along the river, and you should leave the river shortly after Zell and go along the Altlayer Bach towards Altlay.

Interestingly, according to [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=Koblenz,%20Deutschland&daddr=Frankfurt%20Hahn%20Flughafen,%20Deutschland&hl=de&geocode=Fc9iAAMdhMxzACmdfSN2V3u-RzFgs9oQ1dQiBA%3BFc0c-gIdxNduACFYHEaWbpyyPSlfdbQmBBi-RzFYHEaWbpyyPQ&aq=0&oq=Frankfurt-&sll=50.146358,7.456784&sspn=0.741877,1.234589&vpsrc=6&t=h&dirflg=b&mra=ls&ie=UTF8&ll=50.085344,7.440491&spn=0.37141,0.617294&z=11&lci=bike), there is a shorter alternative route that continues down the Rhine, leaves it at Bad Salzig and includes a long stretch of the [Schinderhannes-Radweg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinderhannes-Radweg).

Answer (score 6):

There is also a good website for routeplaning on bicycles, which will help you. You can even see the gradients of the road and have different options (only bicycle paths, the fastest path, the shortest path ...). I tried it myself and find it more accurate most times than google maps for bicycles.

[RadroutenPlaner](http://www.radroutenplaner.nrw.de/RRP_sprachen_02.html)

My suggestion would be: take only bicycle routes and try to avoid gradients. The RadroutenPlaner would suggest a route of 86,8km, having a gradient of 849m and (by traveling with 15km/h) you would need 5:47h.

If you have a GPS, you can even download the route you calculated.

[image: from Koblenz to Frankfurt Hahn Airport]

**Important Notice**
Don't try to navigate to "Frankfurt Airport" ... didn't know that either, but Frankfurt has a district called "Flughafen" (which means airport), so it will navigate you in the wrong direction ;)
Try *Flughafen Frankfurt-Hahn*

Comment: Is this your site?

Comment: @MarkMayo my first idea was also that it's a spam or self-promoting, but it's official site of North Rhine-Westphalia

Comment: @Dirty-flow is right, it's an offical site, not mine. It's from North Rhine Westphalia, but it also works for some other states of Germany (like for example Hessen and Rheinland Pfalz, where Koblenz and Frankfurt are located).

Comment: @Ferox you can make your answer better by icluding some details or a screenshot that directly answer the question (for the route Koblenz - Flughafen Hahn)

Comment: Cool, always worth checking especially with new users. Thanks @Ferox!